# FormatText Statement Explanation needed

Tags: xml, syntax

I'm trying to make some changes to the way text is formated in a script.

Script currently is : `<Title FormatText="{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}">`

I cant find an explanation of the "FormatText" statement so I don't know what the correct operators / syntax is.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code that is trying to execute the format, it's difficult to give a good answer. But I suspect they are probably using `String.Format` to generate the output.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Comment: Thanks mgnoonan this may help. The code is built into CRM2011 and this is a fraction of XML. Thanks again

Comment: Thank yous come in the form of green check marks, if that was the right answer! :)